# Upgrade of Managed package fails with <Data Not Available> error email

Tags: managed-package, isv, error, install

When I tried to upgrade a customers org with the newest version of our managed ISV package I received this error email minutes after I finished the installation wizard:

> Your request to install package "MYPACKAGE" was
>   unsuccessful. None of the data or setup information in your
>   salesforce.com organization was affected.
>
> If your install continues to fail, contact Salesforce CRM Support
>   through your normal channels and provide the following information.
>
> Organization: UP2GO Int'l LLC (Partner Main) (00DG0000000k3V6) User:
>   John Doe (005G0000003xkNx) Package: MyPackage (04td0000000AwuF)
>
> Problem:
>
> 1. Data Not Available The data you were trying to access could not be found. It may be due to another user deleting the data or a system
>      error. If you know the data is not deleted but cannot access it,
>      please look at our support page.
>
> Data Not Available
>
> The data you were trying to access could not be found. It may be due
>   to another user deleting the data or a system error. If you know the
>   data is not deleted but cannot access it, please look at our https://login.salesforce.com/services/auth/sso/00D30000000XsfGEAS/HTAuthProvider?startURL=%252Fapex%252Fhtdoor%253Fbody%253D%25252Ftrain%25252FonlineSupport.jsp%2526loc%253Dsupport%2526language%253Den_US%2526release%253D186.12.41%2526instance%253DNA11&site=https%3A%2F%2Fhelp.salesforce.com', 'Help', 1024, 768,
>   'width=1024,height=768,resizable=yes,toolbar=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,directories=no,location=yes,dependant=no',
>   false, false);" title="support (New Window)">support page.
>
> Thank You, salesforce.com

I opened a case with Support, but hope to find a solution faster here ;).